# HttpServer java чтение html в папке

Tags: java, веб-сервер

Я написал простой сервер на Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int port = 80;
    if (args.length > 0) {
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
    ResultSet resultSet = new Database().getCalendars();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String URL = "/web-today-" + resultSet.getString("user_id");
        System.out.println(URL);
        server.createContext(URL , new MyHandler(resultSet.getString("user_id")));
    }
    server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + port);
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

    private String userId;

    public MyHandler(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        String response = "";
        try{
            String fileName = "calendars/webCalendars/calendars-today/web-" + userId + ".html";
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                response = line;
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            response = "ERROR IN LOADING PAGE";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Я хотел бы при добавлении нового Юзера в таблицу - автоматически "добавлять ссылку на страницу" в Java HttpServer.

Как у меня работает основная программа: юзер зарегался, сразу генерируется html-страница с его профайлом с именем `web-USERID.html`. Далее я хочу добавить данную страницу в HttpServer, чтобы юзер мог на нее зайти по запросу `www.example.com/web-today-USERID.html`.

Грубо говоря, мне надо, чтобы все файлы в `calendars-today/..` могли открываться в браузере. Файлы в той папке могут удаляться или добавляться новые!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После нижеследующих телодвижений все содержимое папки `c:/webapp` будет доступно по `http://localhost:8080/test/`

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
server.createContext("/test", new StaticHandler("/test", "c:/webapp"));
...
server.start();
```

---

```
public class StaticHandler implements HttpHandler {

    private String routePath;
    private String fsPath;

    private Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
        put("html", "text/html");
        put("css", "text/css");
        put("js", "text/javascript");
        put("json", "application/json");
        put("svg", "image/svg+xml");
    }};

    public StaticHandler(String path, String filesystemPath) {
        routePath = path;
        fsPath = filesystemPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange http) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = http.getResponseBody();
        http.getRequestBody();
        String request = http.getRequestURI().getRawPath();
        byte[] result;
        int code;
        try {

            try {
                String path = fsPath + request.substring(routePath.length());
                System.out.println("requested: " + path);
                result = read(new FileInputStream(path)).toByteArray();
                String ext = request.substring(request.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                if (headers.containsKey(ext))
                    http.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Type", headers.get(ext));
                code = 200;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                result = (404 + " " + request).getBytes();
                code = 404;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            result = sw.getBuffer().toString().getBytes();
            code = 500;
        }

        http.sendResponseHeaders(code, result.length);
        outputStream.write(result);
        outputStream.close();
    }

   static ByteArrayOutputStream read(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        buffer.flush();
        return buffer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Сейчас поэкспериментирую

Comment: Можно еще "адаптировать код" не под винду. я про момент с `c:/webapp`. Или это не связано с виндой?

Comment: @Antonio112009 просто у меня дома винда, а код кросс-платформенный

Comment: Все, то гда я понял момент с `c:/webapp`)) Жду добавление кода

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90409/discussion-between-antonio112009-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Comment: Спасибо за верный ответ, да, это то, что мне надо!